# R SQLDF extract only a value

Tags: r, sqldf

I have read in a CSV file and want to run a query on it

The query is in the form

`count_a = SELECT sum(A) as COLS FROM file where year = "2012"`

I use this:

`sum_of_a = all_data = read.csv.sql(data_all, count_a)`

I get back

```
    COLS
1   85221
```

When I print(sum_of_a) - how do I get just the number part?
I have tried sum_of_a.values[0] also tried sum_of_a["COLS"] and get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `[[` or `$`

```
sum_of_a$COLS
```

or with `[[`

```
sum_of_a[[1]]
```

In `R`, the indexing starts from 1